# SQL, calculating SUM of two columns A, B based on value(flag) in column C, performance

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, case

Lets say you have table `Table1` with following columns:
`| A | B | C | D |`
and you need to produce following result set via `SELECT and GROUP BY D statement`

`| X1 | X2 | X3 | X4 | X5 | X6 |`

where those columns are defined as:

```
X1 = sum(A) if C = 0 OR 12
X2 = sum(B) if C = 0 OR 12 
X3 = sum(A) if C = 2 
X4 = sum(B) if C = 2
X5 = sum(A) if C = 1
X6 = sum(B) if C = 1
```

Values for column `C` goes from `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 12`.
One approach would be to use `subquery` for each calculation such as:

```
SELECT
    (
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(A), 0.00)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE C = 0 OR C = 12
    ) AS 'X1',
    (
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(B), 0.00)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE C = 0 OR C = 12
    ) AS 'X2',
    (
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(A), 0.00)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE C = 2
    ) AS 'X3',
    (
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(B), 0.00)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE C = 2
    ) AS 'X4',
    (
      SELECT  COALESCE(SUM(A), 0.00)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE C = 1
    ) AS 'X5',
    (
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(B), 0.00)
      FROM Table1
      WHERE C = 1
    ) AS 'X6'
FROM Table 1
WHERE C IN (0, 1, 2, 12)
GROUP BY D
```

Performance wise, to me seems like a brute-force. Probably same thing could be converted using `CASE` instead `subqueries`, but i doubt it would affect performance in positive way? or it should? **Any other/better approach(es) in mind?** As an general question how number of subqueries affects performance?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: hi @Shawn thank you for looking into question. Would be more than happy if solution would also cover `5.7`. But recent ones `8.x.x` also could be used.

Comment: 5.7 doesn't have windowing functions (8 does), which would probably be pretty quick.  Gordon probably has the most flexible answer that will work across multiple versions and is fairly standard SQL. And quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select d,
       sum(case when c in (0, 12) then a else 0 end) as x1,
       sum(case when c in (0, 12) then b else 0 end) as x2, 
       sum(case when c = 2 then a else 0 end) as x3,
       . . .
from t
group by d;
```

This should definitely be faster than subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Gordon beat me to the answer. This can be done with pretty standard SQL.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2f714/7)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a int, b int, c int, d int) ; 

INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c,d)
SELECT 1,1,0,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,0,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,0,20 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,0,20 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,1,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,1,20 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,2,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,2,30 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,3,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,5,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,12,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,5,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,5,10 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,5,20 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,1,5,20
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT d
    , sum(CASE WHEN c IN (0,12) THEN a ELSE 0 END) AS x1 
    , sum(CASE WHEN c IN (0,12) THEN b ELSE 0 END) AS x2
    , sum(CASE WHEN c = 2 THEN a ELSE 0 END) AS x3
    , sum(CASE WHEN c = 2 THEN b ELSE 0 END) AS x4
    , sum(CASE WHEN c = 1 THEN a ELSE 0 END) AS x5
    , sum(CASE WHEN c = 1 THEN b ELSE 0 END) AS x6
FROM t1
WHERE c IN (0,1,2,12)
GROUP BY d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2f714/7/0)**:

```
|  d | x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 |
|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
| 10 |  3 |  3 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |
| 20 |  2 |  2 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |
| 30 |  0 |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0 |  0 |
```

If you have a lot of values in `c` that aren't in `0,1,2,12`, then you can use the `WHERE` to pare down the result set you'll be aggregating. Otherwise, you can probably remove it.

Comment: very nice example. Just thinking, how would you expand the example and add two new columns `x7`, `x8` where `x7 = x4 - x2` and `x8 = x5 - x3`. That would introduce subqueries and little bit more complexity to the example.

Comment: @Srle See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5846e/1. I did two things: I added your request, and I also added in some test cases that show `NULL` values.

Comment: one of the most completed and very well explained answers that i saw on SO most recently, thanks